# Combine two pandas df's based on a partial match

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

Sorry about the vague heading, it's difficult to explain.

I have two `pandas df's` which contain related information. One contains data that displays timestamps on when an event should occur and the other displays data on when that event actually occurs.

I want to determine the difference between these timestamps. The issue is the values that represent each where these events are vary slightly. They are similar but aren't identical. So it's hard to `merge` or `concatenate` on a identical value.

The first `df` is when the events should occur:

Example df:

```
Sched = pd.DataFrame({
        'E' : ['Home','Shops','Away','Shops','Home'],     
        'F' : ['10:00:00','11:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','14:00:00'],        
        'G' : ['No: 10', 'No: 2', 'No: 1','No: 3','No: 11'],                                 
        })
```

So the place where events occur are labelled in `Column E`. e.g. `Home, Shops, Away`.

This df displays when the event actually occurs:

```
Meet = pd.DataFrame({
        'A' : ['10:00:05','11:00:05','12:00:05','13:00:05','14:00:05'],
        'B' : ['HOME LOCK','AWAY HR','SHOPS JK','HOME LOCK','SHOPS JK'],
        'C' : ['No:','No:','No:','No:','No:'],         
        'D' : ['10', '1', '2','11','3'],                               
        })
```

So the data in `Column B` is at the same meeting (Home, Away, Shops) but theres a few differences. It's all in capital letters, there's a few additional strings to some too.

I have considered trying to map the appropriate codes in using:

```
Code = pd.DataFrame({
        'H' : ['HOME LOCK','AWAY HR','SHOPS JK'],
        'I' : ['Home','Away','Shops'],                                        
        })

Meet['B'] = Meet['B'].map(Code.set_index('H')['I'])
```

That way I could merge the output with the `sched df`. The problem is theres hundreds of codes and they continuously change each day.

Is there a way to do a partial match of values? As in, can values which are largely the same be merged?

Comment: Are you always guaranteed that the first word in col B of Meet is a valid key in column E of Sched?

Comment: @coldspeed yes, the first word will always be the same. Meet is always caps though and Sched is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe is possible use [`title`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.title.html) with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) if first word match:

```
Meet['E'] = Meet.B.str.title().str.split().str[0]
print (Meet)
          A          B    C   D      E
0  10:00:05  HOME LOCK  No:  10   Home
1  11:00:05    AWAY HR  No:   1   Away
2  12:00:05   SHOPS JK  No:   2  Shops
3  13:00:05  HOME LOCK  No:  11   Home
4  14:00:05   SHOPS JK  No:   3  Shops
```

Another more general solution is use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by possible words joined by `|` for regex OR:

```
Meet['E'] = Meet.B.str.title().str.extract('(Home|Away|Shops)')
print (Meet)
          A          B    C   D      E
0  10:00:05  HOME LOCK  No:  10   Home
1  11:00:05    AWAY HR  No:   1   Away
2  12:00:05   SHOPS JK  No:   2  Shops
3  13:00:05  HOME LOCK  No:  11   Home
4  14:00:05   SHOPS JK  No:   3  Shops
```

what should be more dynamic if create pattern by unique values of `E` column of `Sched` with `\b` for word boundary:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in Sched.E.unique())
print (pat)
\bHome\b|\bShops\b|\bAway\b

Meet['E'] = Meet.B.str.title().str.extract('(' + pat + ')')
print (Meet)
          A          B    C   D      E
0  10:00:05  HOME LOCK  No:  10   Home
1  11:00:05    AWAY HR  No:   1   Away
2  12:00:05   SHOPS JK  No:   2  Shops
3  13:00:05  HOME LOCK  No:  11   Home
4  14:00:05   SHOPS JK  No:   3  Shops
```

Comment: Haven't seen ''.join being used to print a regex pattern before. This will be very helpful. Thanks.